# how to insert values in a row of one table into the column of another table using SQL statement

Tags: sql, qsqlquery

I have two tables T1 and T2.

T1:

```
  T1CN1      T1CN2      T1CN3
  ------     ------     ------
  T1C1R1     T1C2R1     T1C3R1
  T1C1R2     T1C2R2     T1C3R2
  T1C1R3     T1C2R3     T1C3R3
  T1C1R4     T1C2R4     T1C3R4
  T1C1R5     T1C2R5     T1C3R5
  T1C1R6     T1C2R6     T1C3R6
```

T2:

```
  T2CN1    T2CN2    T2CN3    T2CN4    T2CN5    T2CN6    T2CN7 
  ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------
  T2C1R1   T2C2R1   T2C3R1   T2C4R1   T2C5R1   T2C6R1   T2C7R1
  T2C1R2   T2C2R2   T2C3R2   T2C4R2   T2C5R2   T2C6R2   T2C7R2
```

T3:

```
  T3CN1
  ------
  T3C1R1
```

I need a statement to give the result as:

Result:

```
  T1CN1     T1CN2     T1CN3
  ------    ------    ------
  T1C1R1    T2C2R1    T1C3R1
  T1C1R2    T2C3R1    T1C3R2
  T1C1R3    T2C4R1    T1C3R3
  T1C1R4    T2C5R1    T1C3R4
  T1C1R5    T2C6R1    T1C3R5
  T1C1R6    T2C7R1    T1C3R6
```

if T3C1R1=T2C1R1

else it should copy the second row of the T2 into the second column of T1

How can I achieve this using an SQL statement?

FYI,

T1CN1 -----> Table1 columnname1(first column name of T1)

......

T1C1R1 -----> Table1 column1row1(data at C1R1 of T1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use join,join T1 and T2 on the required column. 
Use the case statement to check value and change the value if required.

Insert into T1 (column list)
Select T1C1,
Case when T1C1='Value x' then T1C1 else T2C2 end
From T1 join T2 on 
T1C1=T2C2